# Ngram in python with start_pad

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, nltk

i'm know in python i'm take some basic thing about list and tuple but my not full understand  the my cod i want create list have three index in each index have tuple with tow index like this [('~','a'),('a','b'),('b','c')] the first index in tuple have tow char or the length context when have  like this  [('~a','a'),('ab','b'),('bc',' c')] can any one help my ? Her my code

---

```
def getNGrams(wordlist, n):
ngrams = []
padded_tokens = "~"*(n) + wordlist
t = tuple(wordlist)
for i in range(3):
  t = tuple(padded_tokens[i:i+n])
  ngrams.append(t)
return ngrams
```

Comment: how does look like your output?

Comment: The my output when enter 1gram [('~',), ('a',), ('b',)] the when bigram [('~', '~'), ('~', 'a'), ('a', 'b')] the wordlist is “abc”

Comment: Write how like?!

Comment: The not true output because I don’t know how specific index in tuple the some char not appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, You can change the function like below and get what you want:

```
def getNGrams(wordlist, n):
    ngrams = []
    padded_tokens = "~"*n + wordlist
    for idx, i in enumerate(range(len(wordlist))):
        t = tuple((padded_tokens[i:i+n], wordlist[idx]))
        ngrams.append(t)
    return ngrams

print(getNGrams('abc',1))
print(getNGrams('abc',2))
print(getNGrams('abc',3))
```

Output:

```
[('~', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c')]
[('~~', 'a'), ('~a', 'b'), ('ab', 'c')]
[('~~~', 'a'), ('~~a', 'b'), ('~ab', 'c')]
```